# Line paragraphing - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been trying to paragraph my lines(text) and get the right font on my app. My question seems crazy but please help me out. This is what I have tried so far.

**Line.axml**

```
  <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:text="Caption"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:maxLines="50"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"

            />
```

Current Display

[image: Current Display]

Expected Display

[image: Expected Display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected font you want looks like the `Roboto Regular` to me. Then you can simply change your `android:fontFamily="Times New Roman"` to `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"`.

`Roboto` is the standard typeface on Android. And you can check [Roboto & Noto fonts](https://material.io/guidelines/resources/roboto-noto-fonts.html) to find the latest version of `Roboto`:

[image]

So the font family are as following:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)
```

together we can define the font also with  `android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"`.

In addition, if you want to use your custom font, you can refer to this official doc: [Working With Fonts](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html).